# Function binding does not work, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, this, call, bind

so I have created two objects: person and Tim.

I would like to bind **logInfo** function to the Tim but when I call this with binding, it keeps giving me:

1. undefined job
2. undefined phone

Here is the code:

```
function hello() {
console.log('Hello')
}

const person = {
firstNAme: 'A',
age: 26,
sayHello: hello,
sayHelloWindow: hello.bind(document),
logInfo: function (job, phone) {
    console.group(`${this.firstNAme} info: `)
    console.log(`name is: ${this.firstNAme} and the age is: ${this.age}`)
    console.log(`Job is: ${this.job}`)
    console.log(`Phone is: ${this.phone}`)
    console.groupEnd()
  }
}

const Tim = {
firstNAme: 'Tim',
age: 22
}

const infoTim = person.logInfo.bind(Tim)
infoTim('clown', '100100-10010')  // returns undefined values, why?
```

Do I seem to miss something?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You never use the parameters `job` and `phone`. You could do `this.job ?? job` and `this.phone ?? phone`, but it’d make a lot more sense to use normal class inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

In `logInfo` function, remove `this` for `job` and `phone` as they are being accepted via arguments and are not property of `Tim` object. `this` always refers to current object and `this.something` points to property of the object .

Refer updated code

```
   function hello() {
      console.log('Hello')
   }
    
    const person = {
    firstNAme: 'A',
    age: 26,
    sayHello: hello,
    sayHelloWindow: hello.bind(document),
    logInfo: function (job, phone) {
        console.group(`${this.firstNAme} info: `)
        console.log(`name is: ${this.firstNAme} and the age is: ${this.age}`)
        console.log(`Job is: ${job}`)
        console.log(`Phone is: ${phone}`)
        console.groupEnd()
      }
    }
    
    const Tim = {
    firstNAme: 'Tim',
    age: 22
    }
    
    const infoTim = person.logInfo.bind(Tim)
    infoTim('clown', '100100-10010')
```